# ASP MVC 2 in server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have built in visual studio a simple MVC 2, just to see if it work on the server where I'm hosting it. The server has .NET 3.5, that's why I'm using MVC 2 and not MVC 3.

I put the files of the project on the server, but I get this error: Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server.

I looked up this error already, I changed the config file, but I was wondering what other things do I have to do, like in visual studio. What are the steps to like wrap up the project and put it in the server?

Any help or useful links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing would be to make sure that you have ASP.NET MVC 2 installed on the server. If not you could do a [bin-deployment](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx). Also you might find the [following article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETMVC/216_Hosting_and_Deployment_of_an_ASPNET_MVC_Application_in_IIS6_and_IIS7.aspx) useful.

Comment: I followed the steps of bin-deployment and In visual studio 2010 i created the application since the beginning as 3.5. This is just a test to see if I can run ASP MVC 2 on the server, which doesn't support MVC, so the bin-deployment thing should work. The server supports FTP, but I published it in my computer as it says on the page.

Comment: When I open the FTP in the host, my files are there but I don't understand how to run it. 
Folders copied after publshing are:bin content scripts views.I wanted to see the index view but I cant it says The resource cannot be found 
my url structure is similar to this http://something.com/folder1/Views/Home/Index
There is a resource called Index.ascx in such folder but when trying to run it it says it can't be found. =S

Comment: If you follow standard routing conventions your url should look like: `http://foo.com/Home/Index`. You cannot access directly files located in the Views folder. That's what MVC is about: it's a controller action that should receive the request and decide which view to render.

Comment: Sorry I did use the Index without the .ascx thing but is not found!, and another question the folder with the controlers was not published when I clicked "published" they should be there right? it has nothing to do with bin-deployment. This application is supposed to work even though the hosting service only has ASP .NET 3.5 framework right? I should be able to run this.

Comment: I solved it, the bin-deployment worked fine I only had to add a change to Global.asax, in the routings i added an extension "aspx", it was something like {controler}.aspx/{action} etc!
Thank you so much for your answer Darin Dimitrov!!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the steps are:

1) Compile your application in Visual Studio.

2) ???

3) Profit.

Seriously though, you haven't provided enough information to diagnose the problem.